# align environment has too much white space

Tags: math-mode, align

How can I let the following code look good ?

```
\begin{align*}
&\text{Als} &&a,b \in H\\ 
&\Rightarrow   &&a,b\in H_1 \land a,b \in H_2 &&\text{Definitie van doorsnede}\\
&\Rightarrow  &&ab^{-1}\in H_1 \land ab^{-1}\in H_2 &&\text{Group axioma's}\\
&\Rightarrow  &&ab^{-1}\in H  &&\text{Definitie van intersectie}\\
&\Rightarrow  &&H\leq G &&\text{Ondergroep test}
\end{align*}
```

No there is just way too much whitespace. Is there a way to control the amount of whitespace ?

Hm.. in codecogs it does look good. So this is how I would want it to look:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the desired result can be produced by `alignat*` -- but then you have to manage the spacing yourself:

```
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&\text{Als}\quad  &&a,b \in H\\ 
&\Rightarrow {} &&a,b \in H_1 \land a,b \in H_2 &&\text{Definitie van doorsnede}\\
&\Rightarrow {} &&ab^{-1} \in H_1 \land ab^{-1}\in H_2 \quad &&\text{Group axioma's}\\
&\Rightarrow {} &&ab^{-1} \in H  &&\text{Definitie van intersectie}\\
&\Rightarrow {} &&H \leq G &&\text{Ondergroep test}
\end{alignat*}
```

**edit:** a look at the `amsmath` documentation would be salutary -- `texdoc amsldoc` on a tex live system.

the (required) argument after `\begin{alignat}` was introduced to make it possible to determine (for ease of macro programming, it appears) the width of a particular single column so that it can be treated in a special manner if necessary.  the value is equal to the number of `&`s in the line with the most, minus one.  an alternate method of calculating the value is given in the user's guide cited above.

Comment: aaah thanks, looks great! why {4} after alignat ?